# array.find() is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, subdocument

I am trying to update a given subdocument inside an array using its id but when i use the vanila javascript array.find() i get undefined. below is the code

```
    let offers = service.offers
    console.log("OFFERS ARE ==========", offers)
    
    const offerIDObject = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(offerID)
    console.log("CONVERTED  ID IS ==========", offerIDObject)

    // Find returns undefined for some reason
    const offer = offers.find((el) => {
        return el._id === offerIDObject
    })
    
    offers.map((el, i) =>console.log("ARE OF SAME TYPES======", typeof(el._id) === typeof(offerIDObject)))

    console.log("THE FOUND OFFER IS=======",offer)
```

[image]

What could be the problem with the find method?

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.valueOf/

Comment: `===` applied to objects compares for referential equality, ie both sides have to point at the very same (as in "same memory location") object, which probably isn't the case if one of them comes from the database and the other one was just created a few lines above ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

objectIds are never the same. you can convert it to string, then compare them like this: `return el._id.toString() === offerIDObject.toString()` or use mongoose .equals() method:

```
const offer = offers.find((el) => {
        return el._id.equals(offerIDObject)    
})
```

both should work.